# How do I use pre-existing Lat/Long data in a SQLite table with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql, geometry, sqlite

I have an application that stores its data in a SQLite database. I can't modify the application or database to add geometry extensions, but it does already have latitude and longitude columns for each row of data it stores (stored in decimal format).

How do I tell QGIS to look at these columns to generate x,y points? If I dump the database to a CSV file, I just have to choose the X field and Y field for lat and long under "Point Coordinates" when adding the layer. I'm essentially looking for a way to do the same, but with a SQLite data source.

Here's how the SQLite data source looks when loaded in QGIS as a vector layer:

[image: qgis data source table]

I'm trying to turn each of those rows into a point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In QGIS, make sure your processing toolbox is visible, then use the "Vector creation" > "Create Points Layer From Table" [tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#create-points-layer-from-table).

[image]

Comment: That did it! That's exactly the dialog I was looking for. I have also never come across this Processing Toolbox before - I think a lot of these tools would have saved me hours in the past. Cheers!